# Separation of dried blood using solvent

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, biochemistry

What is the best solvent to separate the metabolites from dried blood?

Comment: Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Comment: What metabolites? Short of knowing that, your question sounds a bit vague.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to the procedure that follows from Ref. [[1]](https://www.mdpi.com/2218-1989/12/2/94) a mixture of water and methanol is an appropriate solvent:

> Metabolites from DBS samples (3.2 mm diameter punch) were extracted onto 96-well plates in 100 µL 80% methanol. The supernatants (75 µL) were transferred onto new plates, dried under nitrogen, reconstituted in 75 µL 2.5% methanol, and transferred (65 µL) onto the final plates before injection.

Blood metabolites, unless associated with a carrier such as liposomes or BSA, are significantly water-soluble (salts or polar compounds). Methanol is thoroughly miscible with water but lowers the polarity of the mixture helping solubilize less polar compounds such as lipids, and methanol is also easily removed by evaporation.

**Reference**

1. Olarini, A.; Ernst, M.; Gürdeniz, G.; Kim, M.; Brustad, N.; Bønnelykke, K.; Cohen, A.; Hougaard, D.; Lasky-Su, J.; Bisgaard, H.; et al. Vertical Transfer of Metabolites Detectable from Newborn’s Dried Blood Spot Samples Using UPLC-MS: A Chemometric Study. Metabolites 2022, 12, 94. https://doi.org/10.3390/metabo12020094